# How large can individual Dyson segments be before they get torn apart by tidal forces or orbital variations?

Tags: physics, orbital-mechanics, mathematics, dyson-spheres

Yet another follow up question in my Dyson sphere series. Assuming the arrays are orbiting at 1 AU, the distance between an inclination of 0.01 degrees is 26,109,754 meters, meaning that there must be 36000 orbiting arrays per circle, or a total of $36000^2=1\ 296\ 000\ 000$ arrays. This is way too much, so humans want to have as few arrays as possible so they can track them easily. However, they are worried about the orbital variation between each point on each segment, as such state vector variations could cause the destruction of the segment. Assuming a yield strength of 1000 MPa, how large could such a segment be?

Comment: Why is it "too many arrays to track"? It isn't that much for a computer, let alone many computers on each array. You can even have each just minding the direct surroundings and navigate that way.

Comment: Why would you believe that tracking 1.3 billion thingies is such a daunting task? For a real-life example, consider that a telecommunications company must process day after day all [call detail records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_detail_record) (CDRs) representing the calls made on that day, for the rather compelling purpose of billing. The are quite a few telecommunications companies which routinely process over a billion CDRs per day, and counts in the hundreds of millions per day are very common. (Or consider the citizen identity database of China.)

Answer (score 1):

This question is somewhat ill-poised as-is, but I'll try to answer it.

The first issue is that the extent of the array along the orbit doesn't really matter. A loop of string all the way around the orbit would work just fine. (Well. In practice it wouldn't for a multitude of reasons.)

But this is a Dyson swarm. A 1d segment doesn't really help. What you want is something that can collect sunlight.

Let's build as thin as possible, so we don't need to worry about radial tides too much. Then the main issue is normal tides. If I put a disk in orbit facing the sun, the sides prograde and retrograde are fine, but the sides normal and anti-normal will try to fold in. Left to themselves they would end up in orbits that take them back to the center of the disk in a quarter-orbit.

Unfortunately, compressive strength on large scales rapidly approaches zero. So what can we do?

Well, we can spin the disks. This essentially replaces compressive stress with tensile stress. Be aware that it makes keeping the disks oriented towards the sun much more complex, although given that each disk is essentially going to be a giant solar sail *anyway* you can probably compensate by adjusting opacity or reflectivity. (That being said, I have *not* run the numbers on the amount of change in opacity that would be required. It's entirely possible that e.g. it turns out that there's not enough sunlight to be able to do so or somesuch.)

This requires knowing the density of the disks, not just the tensile strength. Let's say for the sake of argument that the density of the disks is 8g/cm^3, and that the disks are uniform. (For a more thorough calculation you would want to split this into mass per unit area of the non-structural components, and density and tensile strength of the structure, but this is a half-decent first approximation). (If you're wondering where 8g/cm^3 comes from, it's the approximate density of steel. I'm guessing you're probably using something stronger than steel - but you also want solar panels or somesuch not just structure.)

I'm assuming that the segment is small enough that I can ignore the difference between a spherical sector and a disk.

The tidal acceleration in the radial plane is (approximately) `2*deltaR*G*M_sun/R^3`. The tidal acceleration in the normal plane is 1/4 that.

The hoop stress of a spinning disk is `density * radius^2 * angular velocity^2`.

So. We want to know how large we can make the disk, assuming that in the normal direction the net acceleration is >= 0, and hoop stress is < 1000MPa in the prograde/retrograde direction.

Let's look at the first constraint first. We have `angular velocity^2 * radius >= 1/2 *radius*G*M_sun/(1AU)^3`, or `angular velocity >= sqrt(1/2 *G*M_sun/(1AU)^3)`, or `angular velocity >= 1/(82 days)`. (This cancels out very nicely!)

For our second constraint, we have `8g/cm^3 * radius^2 * angular velocity^2 <= 1000 MPa`. Rearranging, this is:

```
radius <= sqrt(1000 MPa / 8g/cm^3) / angular_velocity
radius <= 353m/s / angular_velocity
```

Plugging in everything, we have a maximum radius of ~8 light-seconds. (Or alternatively, approximately 190 of these disks could form a full orbit.)

Unfortunately, this is large enough that I would *not* trust these calculations. In particular:

1. I assumed that the disk has no out-of-plane forces resulting from the difference between a disk and a spherical sector.
2. I ignored the difficulties resulting from gyroscopic effects of the disk.
3. I ignored self-gravitation of the disk.
4. These disks are going to be going through rather severe stress cycles. Depending on how long you want your Dyson swarm to last, you may want to limit your maximum stress so that the disks take longer to tear themselves apart.
5. These disks have a significant amount of rotational inertia. This poses interesting questions as to how you would spin them up to speed, and also means that they could potentially cascade-fail if the density of the Dyson swarm is large enough.
6. I ignored potential stability issues resulting in resonances between disks and orbital period / other disks / planets / etc / etc.
7. These numbers are insane enough that it's entirely possible I miscalculated somewhere.

...but I would, however, take this as indicating that you could make a rotating solar array at 1AU fairly large before *material* constraints start becoming an issue.

Comment: Sci-fi trivia. The loop around the sun is not stable.  This has been widley known since the publication of the novel _Ringworld_ by Larry Niven. At a sci-fi convention in Boston, the students from MIT showed up and explained to Niven that they had run the math, and the ringworld is not stable. So in the sequel he added tech that stabilized it.

Comment: Yep, a loop of string around the sun rotating at faster than orbital velocity is in an unstable equilibrium.